# Tukey Test and Linear Regression

Tags: regression, categorical-data, tukey-hsd-test

Say there are four groups, (a,b,c,d), for one feature in a dataset with many features. I am trying to predict a numerical feature y. I perform the Tukey test and find that the means of y for groups a and c are statistically different. If I would like to use this feature in a linear regression with dummy variables, how would I choose the binary variables? Could I create a variable for both a and c, with b and d as the baseline, or would this be inaccurate?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single variable with four groups, you need three dummy variables (in regression this is sometimes called the contrast.

You can use whichever group you want as a baseline, it doesn't matter, it will jut change your interpretation slightly. Most statistical software we automatically do all of this for you if you input the data as-is with four levels.

The contrast will look something like this:

```
b c d
0 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 0 0
0 0 0
etc. etc.
```

In this data set, observation set is in group a, which has been "dropped." Your regression will give you three coefficients: one for b, c, and d.

If the coefficient for b is 2, it means group 2 is on on average two units higher for variable Y *than group a*. If c has a coefficient of 3, it means it is two units higher *than group a*. It also implies that c is on average 1 unit higher than b.

Comment: Given the fact that only the difference between the means of a and c are statistically significant, is it "redundant" to have b and d as separate variables?